# What's difference between 昼(hiru) and 正午(shōgo)?

Tags: words

Both 昼{ひる} and 正午{しょうご} mean noon, so are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

「正午」 only has one meaning --- "12:00 p.m."

「昼」 has a few different meanings --- "daytime", "12:00 p.m.", "lunch", "afternoon", etc.

So, the two words are only interchangeable when talking about "12:00 p.m. (= 'noon')".

Strictly speaking, however, it is always better to use 「正午」 when referring to "noon" in order to avoid any ambiguity.

Answer (score 5):

[正午](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/108227/m0u/%E6%AD%A3%E5%8D%88/) is 'noon' as in 12:00 on a 24h clock.

[昼](http://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/leaf/jn2/188633/m0u/%E3%81%B2%E3%82%8B/) can have the same meaning (2 in the dictionary) or just refer to the afternoon/daytime in general (1 in the dictionary).